# Laravel Scheduler not running daily

Tags: laravel-5, cron

I have laravel scheduler set up to run daily and do a db backup. This will not work, but it will if I change to everyMinute(). Why cannot it not run daily, but works fine every minute?

Here is my cron:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

And my command:

```
$schedule->command(
        "db:backup --database=mysql --destination=ftp --destinationPath=`date +\\%Y/\\%m/%m-%d-%Y` --compression=gzip"
    )->daily();
```

Comment: Scheduler is prepared for work and make validations on every minute mode. Looks like it can not run old events that are oldest than actually time. If you want to avoid set the cronjon to every minute, then don't call it in the cron, but concrete command: `0 23 * * * php /var/www/artisan d:backup >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Do you mean to have this command in laravel or in crontab?

Comment: In the cronjob, just adjust the time to fit your needs

Comment: i'm having a problem with the format. says directory is non exsistant. having a problem with: --destinationPath=`date +/\%Y/\%m/\%m-\%d-\%Y`

Comment: Format should be 2016/03/03-30-2016

Answer (score 0):

in Cpanel add this line in cronjobs as Command ... remember to change "user" with you account name

```
0 0 * * php -d register_argc_argv=On /home/user/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```